# Actionscript and database connection APIs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, synchronization, database-connection, multiplayer

There is any API to make connections to the database and client-client? I want to make a online game, with multiplayer mode, and the players need to be connected and synchronized. Which is your best advice?

Comment: To search Google for :) There are so many solutions that there is no 'perfect' one.

Comment: Sad to say, but @AndreyPopov is right. There are many ways to do this, and the most effective solution usually depends as much on the capabilities of your server(s) than on the fact that the client is un Flash.

Comment: You can look in to AppWarp - which has many tutorials for making such games in flash. There is a cloud version (in which you don't have server side control) and an on-premise version (AppWarp S2) in which you can host the server and control its behavior as well.

Comment: I'm trying to use that API (AppWarp and App42 for user management), but I can't do a simple user login, and sessions... Did you used that API? Where did you learn?